# C# ignores null check?

Tags: c#, blazor

Who can explain to me this irrational lame beauty of C# logic in blazor-server?

[image]

Comment: `club` or `creator`?

Comment: @Sajid club. The exception message claims that.

Comment: Incomplete. We'd like to see a full stacktrace, and the complete lifecycle of `club`. And not as pictures.

Answer (score 4):

What is `club`, and does it perhaps have a static `==` operator overload that is not null-safe? For example, the following is possible and broken:

```
bool == (Foo x, Foo y) => x.Id == y.Id;
```

It is broken because it doesn't consider that `x` and/or `y` could be `null`. Using `club == null` will call this broken operator, causing a NRE.

A good way to check is to use `club is object` instead of `club != null`, as the `is object` / `is null` syntax **never** calls static `==` operator overloads.

Comment: It is Entity Framework Core entity. It is initialized in my OnInitializedAsync() method. I think it is because async. But I defenetelly don't understand WHY C# skips null check? club is object -- did not help.

Comment: @dmitry check creator too, then. Debuggers often mislead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You should compare `club` to `null` like this:

```
if (!(club is null) && club.Id > 0)
```

I think NullReferenceException is caused by `==` operator, which can use methods that are not "null safe".

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the reference is null you can use:

```
ReferenceEquals(myObject, null)
```

It is a static method from the Object class itself so basically it can be used everywhere.

Most of the time it will give you the same result as:

```
myObject == null
```

But since the "==" can be overloaded you can have strange behavior.
See [operator overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading).